# Warning when importing data using Read10X about number of entries

Tags: r, seurat

While trying to import RNA seq data into R Studio using Read10X(), I got the following message:

```
Warning message:
readMM(): expected 5059246 entries but found only 4430824
```

Any ideas why this might be or possible solutions?